# Unstack a single column dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    statistics
0      2013-08
1            4
2            8
3      2013-09
4            7
5           13
6      2013-10
7            2
8           10
```

And I need it to look like this:

```
    statistics   X  Y
0      2013-08   4  8
1      2013-09   7  13
2      2013-10   2  10
```

it would be useful to find a way that doesnt depend on the number of rows as I want to use it in a loop and the number of original rows might be changing. However, the output should always have these 3 columns

Comment: If you always have 3 columns, use `pd.DataFrame(df['statistics'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 3))`

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(df.statistics.values.reshape(-1, 3), columns=["statistics", "x", "y'"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is not an unstack operation, you are trying to do a reshape. 
You can do this by using the reshape method of numpy. The variable n_cols is the number of columns you are looking for.

Here you have an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'], columns=['col'])
df
  col
0   A
1   B
2   C
3   D
4   E
5   F
6   G
7   H
8   I
9    J
10   K
11   L

n_cols = 3
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(int(len(df)/n_cols), n_cols))
   0  1  2
0  A  B  C
1  D  E  F
2  G  H  I
3  J  K  L
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data6.csv')
x=[]
y=[]
statistics= []
for i in range(0,len(data)):
    if i%3==0:
        statistics.append(data['statistics'][i])
    elif i%3==1:
        x.append(data['statistics'][i])
    elif i%3 == 2:
        y.append(data['statistics'][i])
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'statistics':statistics,'x':x,'y':y})
data1
```